# I'm losing columns when importing KML file into Fusion Tables

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables

I've some trouble when try to create a Google Fusion table starting from a KML file.
When import is done I note that I've lost some "colums" of data respect at the original KML.
Note that when I see the KML using Google Earth it is ok

Comment: What data does your KML contains? What columns are you missing. It might help to provide a example Placemark.

Answer (score 0):

All of the attributes are contained within the column "description." This is actually an html object and you can see attributes for each entry/row when you click to get an info table in the map view.